# How can I force Wubi to use files from USB?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, wubi, system-installation

I have a Windows 8 Machine, I understand that installing Ubuntu inside Windows 8 is not supported but I followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116638) guide to install the Windows 7 Bootloader. I can successfully boot into Windows 8 but when I run wubi.exe from my USB it still didn't give me the option to install Ubuntu inside Windows. The work around that I found for this was to use

```
G:\wubi.exe --force-wubi
```

It then gave me the install Inside Windows Option but when I install it starts to do its thing but when it finishes extracting the files, it says that it starts downloading the .iso image again which already extracted to the USB. 
My main thing is that I don't want to download it again because I already have it downloaded. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: You don't need to install a Windows 7 bootloader. Wubi works fine on Windows 8 as long as you have a MBR partitioned disk. If not (i.e. new Windows EFI boot with GPT disk) nothing will get Wubi to work. To install without downloading, put the ISO and `wubi.exe` in the same directory before running.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess I'm stuck because in order to install Windows 8 I had to convert my drive to GPT.

Comment: I've installed Windows 8 without GPT disks. Not sure why you had to do that. But anyway - do a normal dual boot then. Better than Wubi.

Comment: ehh, just went ahead and just formatted my computer and installed ubuntu. Had all my files on a 1TB HDD anyway :D